# Decrease the cost of two lists comparisons

Tags: python, time-complexity

I want to minimize the cost of comparisons of two lists that have some words. In the code below `A` has 4 words whereas `B` has 2 words and the cost is `O(n^2)` that is too bad. While for 100 words it can be time consuming. Can I minimize it somehow?

```
A= ["helry", "john" , "kat" , "david"]
d="Helry David"
B = d.lower().split()

for x in range(len(A)):
            for i in range(len(B)):
                if A[x] == B[i]:
                    print("Match = " + A[x])
                else:
                    print("No")
```

Comment: Since you want to print something for every possible combination, it's of course not possible to beat "O(n^2)".

Comment: @StefanPochmann Can we do it by changing the data structure? For example: Store the data in some other DS  other than arrays

Comment: @Amar No. There are N^2 pairs of elements, so you will print N^2 things.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Look at down in answers of #Ferdinand Beyer. Can we use sets?

Comment: @Amar **All** answers posted so far are wrong, as they don't produce the output that your code produces.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann,  unless words repeat then and even then why on earth would you want to iterate over all the words, the OP obviously wants to find any matching words which you can do with a membership test using a set .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know why Amar wants to do that, but apparently they do. Do you mean they **only** want to find matches? There's no indication that that's the case. The "No"-prints exist. And Amar didn't say that they're not needed even when I pointed it out.

Comment: @StefanPochmann. yes realistically they only want matches, the OP is also using range and indexing when they can simply iterate over the lists directly so it would not be a big stretch so get to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets instead of lists (btw these are not called arrays in Python). What you want is the intersection of two sets, which is (on average) `O(min(len(A), len(B))` (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). And since this algorithm is built-in and implemented in C, it is much faster than anything you could write in Python code.

Example (A and B are considered to be defined as before):

```
>>> set(A) & set(B)
{'david', 'helry'}
```

This gives you a set of all values that are contained in both A and B.

Comment: Can you provide the example?

Comment: Look under the question what  Stefan Pochmann is saying. "Since you want to print something for every possible combination, it's of course **not possible** to beat "O(n^2)""

Comment: This solution doesn't average `O(min(len(A), len(B))` but `O(max(len(A), len(B))` (and `O(len(A) + len(B))`). You did refer to the intersection, but I think someone might mistake it for the complexity of the solution, since it's the only complexity you mention.

Comment: @StefanPochmann All I wanted to make clear is that the OP should use sets if he wants fast "contains" checks for larger collections. If he wants speed, maybe he can use sets from the beginning so he does not have to pay the price for their construction. But who knows what he really wants, this is obviously a toy example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort array for O(nlogn) first.
2. Compare it in O(n), because you can safely assume the relationship between certain elements are the same after sorting.

Comment: Any more efficent than your suggestion?

Comment: @Amar if it is possible to give a unique characteristic for every word, you could utilize bucket sort. If so, a complexity of O(len(A)+len(B)) is possible.

Comment: By the way, creating a set means you are using built-in hash function for strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. `O(nlogn)` for sorting `A`.
2. use a binary search for each
   element of `B` in `A` Iit'll take `O(log n)`. For `m` elements in
   `B`, it'll be `O(m*logn)`.

(or) if you use hash, you can do in `O(m)` for `m` elements of `B`.

Comment: Provide the example. If you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in *O(n)* time with sets and testing for *membership* with `in`, you still have to iterate over all the names In `A` but checking if each name is in the setof name is `O(1)`:

```
A = ["helry", "john" , "kat" , "david"]
d = "Helry David"
st = set(d.lower().split())

for name in A:
    if name in st:
        print("Match = {}".format(name))
    else:
        print("No match")
```

Comment: Your code is not working. with `d = "Helry is not David"` . The program is giving different outputs.

Comment: @Amar, there was a typo, this also presumes you just want to find matches which makes sense to me as you never use the element from `d.lower().split()` so why would you need to iterate over every element?